# Namespace replaced while saving a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customlabel, namespace

When I use a Custom Label in a Lightning Component of managed package (with custom namespace), Salesforce changes the file and saves the label with the default namespace.

For example, I save `$Label.mynamespace.labelName` but on the server I found `$Label.c.labelName`

This happens despite the development tool, I tried both Mavensmate and the Developer Console, so I believe it's something of the platform.

Is it normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the similar issues but what i observed was , this works fine now even inside managed package with $Label.c.labelname and there is no need to explicitly add the namespace .

The docs do not mention this but i just tested this with c namespace and it works inside managed namespace .

Comment: Yes, I tried and it works for me as well. So no problem in managed packages, but I wonder why...

Comment: I guess its one of those things thats fixed in v40.0 and docs have missed it