# Unable to update namespace of custom labels in managed package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, customlabel

I have a lightning component as part of a managed package that uses few custom labels. The custom labels are saved with the default namespace like `{!$Label.c.label_name}`. I am trying to update this line with the relevant namespace like `{!$Label.nameSpace.label_name}`. After changing the namespace and saving the component successfully, on refreshing the code reverts to to default namespace i.e. `{!$Label.c.<label_name>}`.
Have looked at this question - [Namespace replaced while saving a lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186339/namespace-replaced-while-saving-a-lightning-component).
Is this a known behaviour or bug? Could not find any official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature, not a bug. Your local code should always be referenced with the "c" namespace. When uploaded in a managed package, it will be referenced correctly. This feature allows you to develop your code in a non-namespaced org, then migrate to a managed package org without having to update your code.